# Accessing the object bound to the ListView row when a Click event is fired?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, data-binding, uwp

Here's my XAML code:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Foo">
        // other controls omitted
        <Button Click="OnClick"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

And here's my event handler:

```
private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    // I have to access here the foo object bound to the listview row
}
```

So how do I access the object bound to the listview item/row?

I have searched everywhere including Microsoft documentation but nothing seems to work :(.

Comment: `((Button)sender).DataContext`

Comment: Thanks. I don't know what to search so I didn't find that hehe